# is it possible to force wordpress to always save thumbnails as 'jpg' not 'png'

Tags: php, post-thumbnails, uploads, attachments, options

I cant see any settings and cant see much in the php api docs regarding this?

for instance if the original file upload is a `png` wordpress converts to `jpg`

Comment: Can you explain why you would want this?

Comment: I don't know why he wants this... I can speak for myself. I'm working on a Wordpress Theme that needs to work on Netscape Navigator 3.0 (Yeah, I know). It doesn't support PNG format.

Answer (score 3):

Here's something I wrote because my clients were using very high quality pngs, when they could be more lossy jpgs for web. Note this still preserves the original image, only changes the thumbnails. Add this to your functions.php

```
<?php

//Force PNG Thumbnails into JPGs
add_filter('wp_generate_attachment_metadata','force_png_to_jpg');

function force_png_to_jpg($image_data) {

  $sizes = array('thumbnail','medium','large');

  $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
  $file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . basename($image_data['file']);

  foreach($sizes as $size){

    if(isset($image_data['sizes'][$size]))
    {
      if( $image_data['sizes'][$size]['mime-type'] == "image/png" ){

        //change format and filename for jpg
        $dest_file = preg_replace('/\.png$/i', '.jpg', $image_data['sizes'][$size]['file']);
        $image_data['sizes'][$size]['file'] = $dest_file;
        $image_data['sizes'][$size]['mime-type'] = "image/jpg";

        //process image into jpg using standard gd lib
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($file);
        $bg = imagecreatetruecolor(imagesx($image), imagesy($image));
        imagefill($bg, 0, 0, imagecolorallocate($bg, 255, 255, 255));
        imagealphablending($bg, TRUE);
        imagecopy($bg, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($image), imagesy($image));
        $bg = imagescale($bg, $image_data['sizes'][$size]['width'], $image_data['sizes'][$size]['height'] );
        imagedestroy($image);

        //set quality and save
        $quality = 80; // 0 = worst / smaller file, 100 = better / bigger file 
        imagejpeg($bg, $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $dest_file, $quality);
        imagedestroy($bg);
      }
    }
  }

  return $image_data;
}
```

Comment: Nice one, altough I would suggest using `get_intermediate_image_sizes()` for `$sizes` source, to be more general :)

Comment: Also, in curr WP `$file = ...` has to be different, because `$upload_dir['basedir']` contains path to current year/month upload directory - which is already contained in `image_data['file']`:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
`$file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $image_data['file'];`

Comment: ...and lastly of course - `imagejpeg($bg, dirname($file) . '/' . $dest_file, $quality);`

Answer (score 1):

The thumbnails will be saved using the mime type of the file.

You will need to create your own functions using a php extension or or library.  WordPress uses [GD](http://www.boutell.com/gd/) but hopefully this will be ported over to [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) by 3.5 Using the API available in the extension you can add hooks and filters to convert the images.  A good starting place would be o look ate the [media_handle_download](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_upload) and [media_sideload_image](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_sideload_image) functions.